# How to change the column set in an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that I need to update depending on whether a field is empty or not.
If it is empty, I need to set column b, else I need to set column c.
However, I can't seem to get it to work as the idea I had will result in a syntax error.
The following is the idea of the query that I have in mind:

```
UPDATE table_a SET
(IF a = '', 'b', 'c') = 'test';
```

I will also need to get a count of the rows updated, therefore I hope that I will be able to update the table by just using 1 update statement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET b = 
      CASE WHEN a = '' 
      THEN 'test' 
      ELSE b 
      END
, c = 
      CASE WHEN a <> '' 
      THEN 'test' 
      ELSE c 
      END
```

**Working Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a823d/1

**How it works:**

Using CASE you check if `a = ''` then `SET b = 'test` otherwise `SET b = b`. Same is done with the column `c`.

Comment: Wow didn't know case could be used like this. Will try it out tomorrow and accept your ans if it works :)

Comment: @KennethLJJ sure. you may also check with fiddle link for testing. :)